# carve bzip2 using foremost

Tags: data-recovery, archive, bzip2

i have a corrupted drive and need to recover the archive files from it. I already successfully used `foremost` to recover the pdf files.

```
foremost -t pdf -i /dev/sda -o /tmp/foremost/pdf
```

however i now want to recover `.bz2` from the drive

```
foremost -t bz -i /dev/sda -o /tmp/foremost/arc
```

This is not working. I probably need a custom conf file to extract theses file types. How would I create such an conf file? Is there some documentation for it?

Comment: Manual states `-c  - set configuration file to use (defaults to foremost.conf)` so look for foremost.conf But I doubt the filetypes need a conf. Seems illogical to have a -t option for a fi;etype =and= a method in a conf.

Comment: tar,bz,gz do not seem to be in the built-in signature set. The documentation for the config file is in `/usr/share/doc/foremost/README.gz`, the format appears to be shared with `scalpel` (a fork of `foremost`?) so you may get some hits for that - for example https://www.garykessler.net/software/index.html#filesigs which appears to contain a compatible `scalpel_GCK.conf` file. Good luck and please let us know if it works.

Comment: thanks for the hint. i downloaded the scalpel conf from the provided link. However that did not work for bz2. which is the most important format for me. However, i created my own conf since bz2 alway has the same header b"BZh". The problem now is that i cannot add a footer, since the bz2 footer does not have a consistent byte representation for the footer but only a bit respresentation. So im still working on it and will post my answer as soon as it works consistently

Answer (score 1):

[Foremost](https://sourceforge.net/projects/foremost/) has not been maintained for years now. [Scalpel](https://github.com/sleuthkit/scalpel) is a fork of Foremost and is still maintained as part of [The Sleuth Kit](https://www.sleuthkit.org/sleuthkit/).

Scalpel can carve `.bz2` files out of the box. You can either use it on the command line or you can install [Autopsy](https://www.sleuthkit.org/autopsy/), a GUI to The Sleuth Kit.